# Spring Boot redirect to current page after successful login

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I have login forms in modal windows. After successful login user is redirected to `/` page. I am trying to find a method to stay on contact page or another page after  login. How to do this? My code is:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**","/js/**","/fonts/**","/images/**","/home","/","/kontakt").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/userlist").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
    http
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could use custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and set `useReferer` to `true`.

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler handler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    handler.setUseReferer(true);
    return handler;
}
```

And in your `configure` method:

```
http
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .successHandler(successHandler())
        .permitAll()
        .and()
```

Answer (score 9):

Just to provide an alternative solution:

```
formLogin()
    .loginPage("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
```

`defaultSuccessUrl` is a shortcut to adding the custom `SuccessHandler`.

Comment: Your answer is not matching the current version of the question. And your answer is flawed, `defaultSuccessUrl` is a shortcut for `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` not for a custom `SuccessHandler`.

Answer (score 8):

I had a weird issue that would cause on login to redirect the user to `localhost:8080/js/bootstrap.min.js`

If anyone else is experiencing an odd redirection on login, which seems to override the `.defaultSuccessUrl()`, then try adding this code below in `SecurityConfig`:

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity security){
    security.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**","/images/**","/js/**");
}
```

Add all your `Resources/static` folders to the `antMatchers()`

Comment: I don't know why you get underrated. Your answer helped me fix the exact same issue.

Comment: worked for me as well (i had a weird redirect to the logo.png)

Comment: it tooks me hours of debuging and trying several solutions before I found your solution ! thnaks.

Comment: Happened to me, too. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can as well do it in your `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` implementation:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, 
HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws 
IOException, ServletException 
{
    //Do your logic;
    response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("referer");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Config is same as [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26833949/2202107),
only luck I had was with extending `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

```
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("HEP HEP");
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only working solution for me, thanks, really. The key was to use ``SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler ``.

Answer (score 2):

I had absolutely the same issue with inadequate redirect after adding bootstrap to my project tree.

Method .*defaultSuccessUrl* with *flag = true* saved me time and lines of code.

```
.formLogin()
   .loginPage("/login")
   .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
   .permitAll()
```

Comment: It's hard to believe that it's so easy! Thank You using this like that .defaultSuccessUrl("/goToThisUrlAfterLogin", true) made my day!

Comment: You saved me hours of troubleshooting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The Spring route, ala extending `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` or `SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler` can be a bit clunky to implement. In the controller (ex. one that processes logins), you can do the header request yourself; ex:

`HttpServletRequest request =null;`

`String priorUrl = request.getHeader("Referer");`

You will notice that you will have the URL prior to either a manual (initiated by user) logout or a session timeout (as handled by Spring session): you'll get an  `https://iAmPriorUrl.com/...`. Then you can do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score -1):

@Jonas All you need to do is add .requestCache() at the end

you config will look like this

```
         .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .requestCache()
```